# TrimSpaces for all XML text

Tags: xml, go

I'm retrieving an XML string from an external web service that I do not control. Some of the data contains empty spaces `<data>    I have leading white space</data>`. How do I trim the space from each element within the XML string?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems are you facing?

Comment: I haven't tried much other than searching for a solution. I have the code in place to receive the XML string and I'm marshaling it into a struct. But I have no idea how to either command the XML marshal to trim the string values and neither do I wan't to write cod that runs through all parts of the struct and trim and re-assign the values manually.

Comment: I reallize this isn't a cod-writing service... I'm just looking for some help on where to even start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the primitives in the encoding/xml package to modify an XML stream on the fly. In this case implementing [xml.TokenReader](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#TokenReader) is a simple solution:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Trimmer struct {
    dec *xml.Decoder
}

func (tr Trimmer) Token() (xml.Token, error) {
    t, err := tr.dec.Token()
    if cd, ok := t.(xml.CharData); ok {
        t = xml.CharData(bytes.TrimSpace(cd))
    }
    return t, err
}
```

Trimmer wraps an underlying decoder and returns a modified token stream. `xml.CharData` represents text nodes. Whenever one is encountered, [`bytes.TrimSpace`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#TrimSpace) is called to trim leading and trailing whitespace. All other tokens are returned unmodified.

[`xml.NewTokenDecoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#NewTokenDecoder) turns `Trimmer` back into a regular Decoder:

```
import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
)

var r io.Reader                          // data source
raw := xml.NewDecoder(r)                 // regular decoder
dec := xml.NewTokenDecoder(Trimmer{raw}) // trimming decoder

var v MyType
err := dec.Decode(&v)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this got me to what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

This could *easily* not work depending on what the data looks like, but if the data is predictable and won't contain `>` anywhere except in XML tags, you could do:

https://play.golang.org/p/4YSpvLFwHjZ

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
)

func main() {
  r := regexp.MustCompile(">(\\s*)")
  xml := "<test>   hello</test><test>  There</test><test>!</test>"
  xml = r.ReplaceAllString(xml, ">")
  fmt.Println(xml)
}
```